# AJAX and JSON. Searching Instagram Pictures

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

It's it possible to use the Instagram API for searching pictures...I mean fro example, If I type Larrypage and search, It should show me most of @larrypage pictures...

Thank you!

Comment: I think your answer may be found here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11634881/how-to-search-instagram-via-api-query :)

Comment: You might try reading the API documentation as it discusses the kinds of search available. For example, user searching tag searching, etc... http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints